# Make chrome use the memory and cpu

Tags: windows, google-chrome, gpu, cpu, ram

So, yesterday I opened task manager in Win 8 (64 bit) and noticed that Chrome (32-bit for some reason) didn't use the whole power my PC has got. So I was running an AI JavaScript program and I noticed that my CPU was running at 1% and Memory was only runnning 120 MB, and that forced me to think why would I wait 5 minutes for it to run instead of somehow boosting it to at least 60%. As far as I know Windows automatically distributes the hardware usage to programs so I'm asking what's the problem:

- Is it because it's x32?
- Is it because I should manually configure windows to give it more power?

Note: I did search Google, but all I got is that people actually complain about High CPU usage and I've got the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 bit doesn't make a difference here. Javascript is inherently single-threaded, so by default (not counting web workers) it won't use more than a single core on your machine. It just cannot. Also memory usage doesn't necessarily tell you how hard a program is working. Some need lots of memory, others only little.

It's up to programs to use the resources of the machine most efficiently; if they don't, there is nothing you can do with Windows to make them run better or faster.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I thought. So you're suggesting that by using web workers I will get it to use all 8 cores.